# Regex gives wrong results

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
>[^\>\s@]*@[^@\s]*\.[a-zA-Z]*<
```

The `@` can't be the first symbol; the string should start and end with `>` and `<`. The string also can have any non-space, non-> and non-@ character before `@` in the middle which is followed by any non-space and non-@ character after which comes a dot and any number of letters.

That is the valid string would be

```
>abc@bef.co<
```

and

```
>@abc@bef.co<
```

wouldn't be valid

for these strings

```
>@abc@def.zx<
>@abc.zx<
>@abc.zx<
```

the first one doesn't match, but the later two match, despite having `@` as the first symbol. Why? How do I fix it?

I tested using https://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` in the `[^\>\s@]*` means that that part repeats 0 or more times, so you could have the character set repeat 0 times, followed by `@`. If you want to make sure it doesn't start with `>@`, match the negative character set once or more with `+` so that something will necessarily come between the `>` and `@`. You also don't need to escape `>`:

```
>[^>\s@]+@[^@\s]*\.[a-zA-Z]*<
```

https://regex101.com/r/LlU0Pc/1